# Memory Management Unit Base Register Limiter Register

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, mmu

In Tanenbaum's operating systems book, in section 1.4, an example is given of an MMU that uses two pairs of base and limit registers to map virtual addresses to physical addresses. Furthermore, it's said that with this structure (the two pairs), it is possible for multiple users to share the same program with only one copy of it in memory. This share is not possible when using just one pair.

Therefore my question: why is it possible to share the same program when using two pair of registers and is not possible on using just one pair?

What I think I understand:

1. When you run an executable (program), a process is created.

So the first doubt in my head begins here:

         How can the same program be shared if each program is a different process?

2. Each process contains its own registers. So each process has a
   program counter register, a stack pointer register and base and
   limit registers.

So how can the registers be shared among two processes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's talking about the program code that is shared. Code is read-only (at least on x86), so sharing it is trivial and saves memory (see Copy-On-Write).

Comment: Show the exact quote and highlight what you don't understand. That makes it easier for us to grasp your question.

Comment: Is it talking about segmented memory management or paged?